# Outlook for mac - Office.context.mailbox.item.body.prependAsync() does work on current UI

Tags: outlook, office365, office-js, office365api

I've been trying to understand why `body.prependAsync()` does not work **only** on Outlook for Mac (**current** UI with Microsoft365 Subscription). For all other browsers and Outlook for Mac (**new** UI with Microsoft365 Subscription), it is working perfectly; meaning the body of the email is being populated correctly. The API version being used is 1.7 and I can see that it's supported in this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/outlook-api-requirement-sets).

The error that I'm receiving in the callback from `body.prependAsync()` is:
**[2006] Invalid Format Error : The format of the specified data object is not valid.**

In the [error code documention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/javascript-api-for-office-error-codes), I see that this error could be caused by the following: The solution developer supplies an invalid HTML or OOXML string, a malformed HTML string, or an invalid OOXML string.

However, the body message needing to be displayed is a properly formatted HTML. I've even tried a regular string but still getting the same error.

The way I am calling it:

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.body.prependAsync(
   '<a href="#">test</a>',
   {coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Html},
   callback
)
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the version of Outlook for Mac and the MacOS version?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Outlook for Mac version 16.43, MacOS: Catalina Version  10.15.6

Comment: We are not able to repro on Outlook version 16.43 .Could you share the steps which you followed ?